# Receive more than one input in controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have a form to submit with more than one input to send via foreach loop like below :

```
@foreach($price as $key => $prices)
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
        {{$date[$key]}}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$date[$key]}}" name="dates{{$key}}">
        <hr>
        {{$prices}}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

when i submit the  form i try to catch like this :

```
foreach ($request->input('dates') as $values) {
    $date[] = $values[0];
}
echo $date;
```

but i get the error that :

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

because i did the following :

```
$request->input('dates')
```

it returns null .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `[]` notation in `name` attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$date[$key]}}" name="dates[{{$key}}]">
                                              -- notice ^   and  ^
```

Without it you currently have something like

```
 <input type="hidden" value="{{$date[$key]}}" name="dates41">
 <input type="hidden" value="{{$date[$key]}}" name="dates42">
```

And these are just two separate fields in `POST` array.

Answer (score 1):

Name of the field should include [] like below.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$date[$key]}}" name="dates[]">
```